# Form of notice to indicate children's prices, and those that are free of cost

Tags: phrase-requests

Our company finds it difficult to word the notice indicating that infants under certain ages are either "free" or go at "half-price".

What should we use?
"Free child age?" or ...? we're not native english talker so it make it lot harder...

thank you

I'm not sure what tags should be used. I will leave it up to the moderator to decide if more should be added.

---

### Edit

As people suggested, i moved the question to: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155126/form-label-to-indicate-childrens-prices-group-and-those-that-are-free-of-cost

Comment: This would be better asked on the EL Learners site. But "Under 10s - half price; Under 5s - free" sounds alright to me.

Comment: @WS2 first does stack have another section for english? second, it's like key value field, which ask the user to enter the age which system should consider to be free or half price... like:   Q: _A_  , Question always is on the left hand side and the Answer is on the right hand side

Comment: Yes, it's called. "English Language Learners". You would find it very helpful. This one is for experienced linguists and native speakers. .

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Anyway, I would go with something like "Maximum age for half price".

Comment: it'a a little long but i'm wonder if there is a better answer, also it's harder for the child with no cost, also note that we should note it to user that we meant infant or child or adult( as we saw many of them, who don't get a thing after explaining things to them... Let me move my Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've cracked it.

Age**:

That's it.

The * symbol indicates a requirement, even though there are age requirements for free or half price it doesn't make sense for the key value entry

The double ** symbol indicates special conditions, and everyone knows to look at the bottom to understand what ** means.   We use the expression 'reading the fine print'

Answer (score 2):

Just put:

KIDS (maximum age) &  UNDER 1/2 OFF

edit:  actually if you're looking for the shortest word count possible you could even get away with taking kids off.

Example:  10 & UNDER 1/2 OFF

Comment: it is usable, although it's a little long, and require us to perform longer explanation to our user

Comment: Trust me, it's not a long sentence in English and your users won't be mad.   I did add an even shorter alternative in case you're interested.

Comment: the issue is not customer get mad because of long sentence, even they will get it with ease, but the issue is we'll use it in a tight form, which we can afford few words: something like (it's tighter than the image): https://cdn.tutsplus.com/mobile/uploads/legacy/143_jQuery-Mobile_Forms/form.png

Comment: What are the real specifics?   Because I can't answer your question accurately without knowing the context.  I could give you a perfect answer that could turn creepy and bad under certain conditions. What are you giving away?   What is the max amount of letters/spaces available?   Actually, just link what you're really working on and delete after if you need to.   I need to know the product or service most of all

Comment: the context is a "key: value" data, which key is the question, and value is a box in front of the question. we ask the Age, and user input numeric value... for example: Age?  4, but we also want to indicate: user this age is for infant which should be free of charge, and in another place, child which is half priced...

Comment: Lol, that's not the context.  Context is basically details that allow you to fully understand the specifics.   But I thought it was for an advertisement.   Honestly, you don't need to put in a key value here, you can just put it on the main form.   Actually, it's better on the main form anyway because more people will see it and tell their friends.    If you must do the key value, all I need to know is how much free white space you can use for each one.   White space is the total amount of characters including the spaces between words.

Comment: 20~25 letter would be greater,but this not work: ` 10 & UNDER 1/2 OFF` it tell user age 10, but i need to ask the age, not tell specify it... also i need another sentence for child which are free of charge

Comment: I'll just post it here instead:  I think I've cracked it.

Age**:

That's it.

The * symbol indicates a requirement, even though there are age requirements for free or half price it doesn't make sense for the key value entry

The double ** symbol indicates special conditions, and everyone knows to look at the bottom to understand what ** means. We use the expression 'reading the fine print'

Comment: Please let me know if that works so I can go to sleep!  : D

Comment: @Sara_Jane let me share it with my friend, look like a good idea, but since the form is multi languages, and require re-writing i hope they accept... just one thing left, how to distinguish age infant which include full discount vs child with half discount with age

Comment: Age**[?] -- make [?] superscript and link a java mouseover box with the age specifics.

Comment: Wait, hoverbox wouldn't work for mobile.   Just do a standard link.   So:   1. Age**[?]  2. [?] superscript font  3. [?] format only the ? with a clickable link to a small pop-up text box that includes your exact requirements.   You should also make sure to add the ** at the end of the page or form.   Covering all of the possibilities is the safest route.

Comment: Any updates?   Curious to see if any of my suggestions worked

Comment: sorry for not saying any thing, the forum ask users to not write down any things like thanks, 1+ or etc